# Firebase Firestore emulator slow for bulk import

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools, bulk-load

The local [Firestore emulator for firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure) seems fairly slow when dealing with bulk data.

I'm trying to simulate a production batch import of ~5,000,000 documents, but after a few thousand records the server is so overwhelmed it slows to a rate of around 5 records/second.

On the topic of [Transactions and Batched Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) firebase says...

> Note: For bulk data entry, use a server client library with parallelized individual writes. Batched writes perform better than serialized writes but not better than parallel writes. You should use a server client library for bulk data operations and not a mobile/web SDK.

That implies to me that I should simply not use the mobile/web SDK, and should make sure I use a server-side SDK/API for imports.

I'm already using the [server client library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries#server_client_libraries) for [node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore).

```
  const batch = firestore.batch();

  for (const record of records) {
    batch.set(
      firestore.collection(collection).doc(record.key),
      record,
    );
  }
  await batch.commit();
```

...and this issue makes me think the local emulator (or firestore in general) can't keep up with a high load.

Comment: did you ever get to the bottom of this ? I am experiencing exactly this issue with the firestore emulator. I tested a few things and it comes down to this. Let me know if you found a solution ?

Comment: I did @Janpan. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3477 The UI itself is slowing down the emulator for bulk imports in my case.